# URI with variable

Tags: ruby, file, uri

I've got a file with uids on separate lines, and I'm trying to include them in a URI.

```
File.open("File Path").readlines.each do |line|

puts line

uid = line 

uri = URI("http://example:port/path/variable=#{uid}&fragment")

res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

puts res.body
```

But I get an error saying "bad URI(is not URI?)".

Could anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try a

```
uid = line.strip
```

The `strip` removes leading and trailing spaces and newlines.

With

```
p uid
```

or

```
puts uid.inspect
```

you may see the real content of the string.

Comment: Ah you genius! If I could vote up I would give you thousands!!! The full string is `example\n` for the new line in the file, is there a way to strip that off?

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on what are you actually feeding it, but I recommend trying these 2 things so you troubleshoot your code well.

- Use `puts "[#{uid}]"` to see what does the `line` variable contain *exactly*. This will surely help you notice if it has a newline in it, for example. The right square bracket will be on the next line and you will know your input is malformed.
- Try constructing the URL like this: `uri = URI("http://example:port/path/variable=#{URI.encode(uid)}&fragment")`. This will help you escape characters which are normally not allowed in an URI / URL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You may use `p uid` or `puts uid.inspect` to see the _exact_ content.

Answer (score 0):

do you means

```
uri = URI("http://example:port/path/?variable=#{uid}&fragment")
```